# Searching excel for a specific patterns. Pivots don't work

Tags: excel, search

I have a comically large excel spreadsheet and I need to find specific data sets based on a pattern. I have no idea where to start with this.

To simplify, each line is a transaction that lists a Person (P) a date (t) and an Item that can be X, Y, A, B or C.

What I would like to do is search that data for the following.

If person P on Date T(+/- 7 days) Received Items X and Y and at least one of Items A, B and Or C, To display that Person with each date and item underneath them.

A point in a good starting place would be appreciated because I feel like I am over my head here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easiest method would be to use conditional formatting, assign your criteria to a fill of any color, then to use "Filter" to filter only by that color.

Assuming that each item has it's own column that can be individually checked (sorry, you did not specify so I am not sure if this is your case), then conditional formatting would be pretty simple.

Let's say your columns are as follows:

```
A.  =P(erson)
B.  =T [Date]
C.  =X [Mandatory item #1]
D.  =Y [Mandatory item #2]
E.  =A [Optional item #1]
F.  =B [Optional item #2]
G.  =C [Optional item #3]
```

And let's assume that you type in "X" under each of your item's columns for all that the person has for that date...

Your conditional formatting would be:

```
=AND( $A1=$H$1 , IF($H$1<>"", OR($B1>=$I$1+7, $B1<=$I$1-7), $B1>=TODAY()+7 
,$B1<=TODAY()-7 , $C1="X" , $D1="X" , OR($E1="X",$F1="X",$G1="X") )
```

So you can leave a blank cell that would be used to type in a person's name, let's just say `H1` and a cell for the date you'd like, `I1`. You can then type in anyone's name in H1 and it would automatically highlight all of the rows that meets your criteria you specified.

Once conditional formatting has highlighted your criteria, you can then go to `Ribbon > Data > Filter`, then `Filter By Color`, and there is your list.

But again, you were not 100% specific so I am not exactly sure if this is what you were looking for.

So just remember to make H1 your cell with your name, and I1 your cell with the date you want to check +/- 7 days against.

Comment: Sorry I wasnt more specific. 

The columns are Date, Customer and Item. The item column can contain only one item. If a customer makes multiple purchases in one day, they will each appear on a separate line with only the Item Column being different between them.

Comment: It's quite alright. Let me know if this will work or how I can adjust it.

Comment: Basically something like  01/01/2001     Smith, Bob    Socket Wrench

Comment: upon further research, It appears that I may have to convert this to ACCESS and make some SQL functions to get what I am looking for.... :-/

also, I need to learn how to use the formatting in the forums better.